# How to implement type declaration with generics?

Tags: generics, typescript

How can I define a function which is an implementation of a type declaration that includes generics?

Here's what I mean:

```
abstract class Base {}
class Sub extends Base {}

declare type BaseFactory = <T extends Base>() => T;
let subFactory: BaseFactory = <Sub>():Sub => new Sub();

console.debug(subFactory()); // expect instance of Sub
```

Unfortunately, this produces the following error:

> `Sub is not assignable to parameter of type Base`

Can this be done?

/edit nevermind, it [actually works in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Base%20%7B%7D%20%20%0D%0Aclass%20Sub%20extends%20Base%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20type%20BaseFactory%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Base%3E()%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0Alet%20subFactory%3A%20BaseFactory%20%3D%20%3CSub%3E()%3ASub%20%3D%3E%20new%20Sub()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.debug(subFactory())%3B%20%2F%2F%20expect%20instance%20of%20Sub). Guess it's a compiler version issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
declare type BaseFactory = <T extends Base>() => T;
let subFactory: BaseFactory = (): Sub => new Sub();

let a = subFactory<Sub>(); // type of a is Sub
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Base%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Sub%20extends%20Base%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20type%20BaseFactory%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Base%3E()%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0Alet%20subFactory%3A%20BaseFactory%20%3D%20()%3A%20Sub%20%3D%3E%20new%20Sub()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20subFactory%3CSub%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a%20is%20Sub))

But I'd do it like this:

```
declare type BaseFactory<T extends Base> = () => T;
let subFactory: BaseFactory<Sub> = (): Sub => new Sub();

let a = subFactory(); // type of a is Sub
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Base%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Sub%20extends%20Base%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20type%20BaseFactory%3CT%20extends%20Base%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0Alet%20subFactory%3A%20BaseFactory%3CSub%3E%20%3D%20()%3A%20Sub%20%3D%3E%20new%20Sub()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20subFactory()%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a%20is%20Sub))

---

#### Edit

If you're using typescript >= 2.3 then you can use default generics:

```
declare type BaseFactory<T extends Base = Base> = () => T;
```

And then you don't need to specify `T` everywhere.

Comment: The problem with the second version is now you have to declare T everywhere BaseFactory is used as property or parameter, where as with the first version, T is only needed when actually invoking the function.

Comment: Check my revised answer